# С# Deep intersection and concatenation in the List<T> in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

Okay.
I have a WebAPI with the ASP.NET that should return an ActionResult value.

My GetAll() should return a value based on my list type.

Like

```
[HttpGet]
            public ActionResult<List<RegistrationCountByMonth>> GetAll()
            {... return val;}
```

The returning value will be something like this.

```
[
  {
    "registrationCountByMonthId": 1,
    "year": 2020,
    "month": 8,
    "numberOfUsers": 13,
    "monthNavigation": null
  }
]
```

I need to remove all of this unwilled fields like registrationCountByMonthId and monthNavigation.

But if I will create something like this

```
var returnVal = crudeReturnInfo.Value.Select(x => new { x.Year, x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}).ToList();
```

Yes, It's cool. But it's return type is List<{Year,Month,NumberOfUsers}>
And I can't return that.

If I'll make a generic List return type - I also need to specify this type in GetAll() method, which is unacceptable.

Thus, my problem is driving deeper than that.
When I will get to the creation of other methods and API requests with parameters.
I should also add to this non understandable type of the list at the end, also some joins query's.

The final signature should be something like following.

```
{ year: 2021, month: 7, registeredUsers: 32, registeredDevices: [{ type: “laptop”, value: “15”}, { type: “mobile phone”,
 value: “8”,}, { type: “tablet”, value: “9”},] }
```

I know how to use AddRange()
But I can't use it, due to invalid parameters in it.

I am kinda confused by now with these Lists.

Is there a way to make this return type all compile time defined ?
Or then, should I for real create a whole data structure only for such a trivial operation ?

Comment: So come up with a name for the `new { x.Year, x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}`, declare it as a class and return `ActionResult<List<that class>>` from `GetAll`?

Comment: To add, the class *`that class`* from above is usually called a ViewModel class. It is very common to have, a little bit of programming overhead in exchange for a lot of clarity. Or if you don't want it, try returning `ActionResult<List<object>>` instead, or even `ActionResult<object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a modern version of c# you write (in a namespace like you would a class):

```
record SomeName(string Year, string Month, int NumberOfUsers);
```

Then you can have a method that returns a `List<SoneName>` and do :

```
.Select(x => new SomeName(x.Year, x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers)).ToList()
```

Which is only a few characters more than you're typing now with your `new { x.Year, x.Month, x.NumberOfUsers}`